# Application server "sharding"

Tags: architecture, cluster-computing

What if, instead of load balancing, connect a client to a cluster node directly?

So:

1. Client sends request to a `Dispatcher`
2. Dispatcher tells the client which service node to use
3. Client continues with given service node until failure. Then client goes to step (1)

Cons

- All service nodes must be visible by clients
- @Alma Do: This configuration leaves your fleet to be way less scalable as you have to persist the client<>node connection which also might mean worse load distribution overall

Pros

- Dispatcher is easier than balancer and requires less resources

Any additional thoughts? If this approach is used somewhere can you share a link to description?

Comment: Why is "dispatcher" easier? More, what you say can be easily implemented in most load-balancing software with "sticky session" or similar flags (in context of web that would be just a cookie). And more - this configuration leaves your fleet to be way less scalable as you have to persist the client<>node connection which also might mean worse load distribution overall

Comment: "Dispatcher" does not route the entire cluster traffic, it distributes nodes addresses, i think it is easier. But you are right - overall load distribution might be worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the dispatcher know what node to send to?  The advantage of load-balancer is that it is getting all the requests, and so it knows what nodes are heavily loaded.  Dispatchers would not, they see the client once, and never again.

Also, how does the client know to go back to the dispatcher when a node fails?  The very nature of failure means that it's not alive to redirect the client.

Comment: As a simple approach dispatcher can use remainder of dividing client id by numer of active nodes. In more complex scenario CPU usage of active nodes can be used. Client goes back to dispatcher when node does not accept connections anymore.

Comment: So you are making a smart client, that knows how to load balance itself..  At this point, do you even need a dispatcher?  Each operation will need to be able to decide whether it's "too slow", or "down", and know to go back to the dispatcher, just take that same algorithm, and put it into the clients.